# Keep excel from auto formating string to number in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that is extracting values from another sheet.
These values are TEXT, but after extracting Excel converts them to number no matter what, even with the columns set to format as text, even using

```
Format( value , "#")
```

The problem is that they are big numbers and it is changing any digits above the 15 count to 0's, I need the numbers as they are.

They are not cut in the reference column(j,3), so it is changing in the process

```
Dim i, col1, col2 As Integer
i = 2
col1 = 4
col2 = 5
    For j = 2 To 2205
        If Cells(j, 3).Value <> "" Then
            If Len(Cells(j, 3)) = 20 Then
                    Cells(i, col1).Value = Format(Cells(j, 3).Value, "#")
                    Cells(i, col2).Value = Cells(j, 3).Row
                    Cells(j, 3).Value = ""
                    i = i + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next j
    i = 2
    col1 = col1 + 2
    col2 = col2 + 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Excel has a limitation of [15 digits of precision](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#bmcalculation), so numbers over 15 digits on either side of the decimal will not be stored at the desired precision.  Have you tried setting the cell format before you insert the value?  Use the line `Cells(i, col1).NumberFormat = "@"` before setting the value.

```
    Dim i, col1, col2 As Integer
    i = 2
    col1 = 4
    col2 = 5
        For j = 2 To 2205
            If Cells(j, 3).Value <> "" Then
                If Len(Cells(j, 3)) = 20 Then
                        Cells(i, col1).NumberFormat = "@"
                        Cells(i, col1).Value = Format(Cells(j, 3).Value, "#")
                        Cells(i, col2).Value = Cells(j, 3).Row
                        Cells(j, 3).Value = ""
                        i = i + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next j
        i = 2
        col1 = col1 + 2
        col2 = col2 + 2
```

Comment: As an added note: You will still be able to work with the values as numbers if you cast them as a [Decimal](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/cdec.php) . Eg: `CDec(Cells(i, col2).Value) + 2`. There is still a limit to the number of digits, but I can't find any documentation on what that limit is. However, I was able to test by adding a 26 digit number to another 26 digit number.

Comment: @Tim, correct.  VBA doesn't have the same limitations as excel...  To display the numbers in the worksheet, you will need to format the cell as text using the NumberFormat property, but in VBA you can cast the value to dec, etc and work with them as precise numbers.  Here is a reference on VBA data types and their limitations.  http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=339929&seqNum=2

Comment: Nice! Now I know the limit is 29 digits. :D And really...who needs more than 29 digits? Even [NASA cuts PI down to 15](http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/edu/news/2016/3/16/how-many-decimals-of-pi-do-we-really-need/)...hmmm...I wonder if they chose 15 because they use Excel?? xD

Comment: @DHL-JDParker that worked only up to 29 digits unfortunately, after that, I think it converted back to number since on a 30 digit "string number" I had 15 zeroes

Comment: If you are performing math functions on these numbers, then yes, 29 digits would be your limit.  If you are just displaying the data, use string data types throughout both VBA and excel...  What are you doing with these numbers that exceed 29 digits??  Lol!